# SQL Flag consecutive (follow) records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am relatively new to SQL and I tried to look for a similar question but I was not sure if the question related to my problem or that the answer might have been above skill level.

I think that the question is simple but I am not sure if the solution is simple.

I have the following sql table output

```
Room      Name       Time in Room     Turnover   Date
11    Mansson     740             NA             1/21/2017
11    Klein       841             NA             1/21/2017
11    Klein       1035            28             1/21/2017
```

I would like to write a query where I can flag fields where the following records are consecutive - Room, Name, Date.

This would flag the last 2 rows where Name is Klein.

Is there a way to do this, if yes can please guide me.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `room`/`name`/`date` flag using ANSI standard window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by room, name, date) > 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as HasDuplicatesFlag
from t;
```